# Setting up a reverse proxy on DD-WRT

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I have a dynamic IP updater set up on my router, and I want to be able to connect to a computer for remote desktop.  I want to be able to connect to a computer on my network with

```
desktopname.mydomain.no-ip.org
laptopname.mydomain.no-ip.org
```

Based on my computer name, I want my router to redirect my request to that computer, so I can have remote desktop, or the same service on each computer.
I have a WRN3500L v1 with DD-WRT v24.  I think what I need to do is install Pound, but I don't know where to start.  Is there any recommendations on how to forward to individual computers?

Comment: Not sure if ddwrt allows multiple domains? If not your best bet is to use ports and setup port forwarding to each host accordingly

Comment: Is it possible to forward ports based on device name, rather than ip address?

Comment: Not AFAIK with ddwrt. Only solution I could think of would be essentially setting up virtual hosts using some kind of web server like Apache/ngnix to be able to use a host as a keyword. So everything went to desktop by default (for example) but any url request containing /laptop/* got redirected to another host. I know that unless i setup specific dyndns software in each host that i can only host one distinct NAT domain from home router

Answer (score 1):

Pound isn't going to work.  Pound is designed for http traffic.

When an HTTP conversation occurs, there's a text value sent from a browser called a host header, which tells the proxy which site (or computer) is being requested.

There are no such things in the RDP protocol.

This is a real pain in the butt, but you can do two things:

1. (Easiest) Do a port-forward on 3389 to server A.  Login to A via RDP, and then login to your other servers from A's desktop.
2. Configure multiple port forwards to your different boxes.  But you must change the port the RDP client is connecting over EACH time.  I don't know why the microsoft crew put it in the registry instead of allowing you to specify it, but that's where it gets changed.